# CSS positioning divs

Tags: css, html

I'm always weak when it comes to positioning divs, but this situation is slightly difficult to find a solution to online. I'm trying to position boxes like so:

```
 _  ___  _ 
|_||   ||_|
 _ |   |
|_||___|
```

Is there a way to avoid defining each one's pixel positions specifically and make them slot into the three columns I've got?

Comment: Can you add more context? What columns? Are those `div`s fixed width? Is that bottom left `div` supposed to be under the top left `div`, or in line with the bottom of the middle `div`?

Comment: Basically, I have no clue what you actually want. Your current HTML/CSS would help.

Comment: By columns I mean the boxes fit into three vertical columns, the first one with two in it. These are fixed width. The bottom left div should just be underneath the other one.

My code for each box without positioning is: 


#box {

 background: #FFFFFF;
 width: 175px;
 height: 300px;
 padding: 5px;
 border: 1px solid #b3b3b3;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rREAh/ is this what you are looking for?

If you need a perfect layout, take a look at the yahoo layout manager: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/layout/

Comment: What I'd like is this (the opposite way round, sorry my mistake): http://jsfiddle.net/rREAh/
but with the top and bottom boxes not separated by a gap, just a small margin that I specify.

Comment: so more something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/rREAh/1/ ? You can easily change the margin through the margin-top css style

Answer (score 5):

Define three containers for each column, and float them to the left:

```
<div style="float:left;width:Xpx"></div>
<div style="float:left;width:Ypx"></div>
<div style="float:left;width:Zpx"></div>
```

Now you can put all your containers in appropriate places in this columns.

Answer (score 3):

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/qXwKT/

**CSS:**

```
.box {
    background: #ffffff;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #b3b3b3;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 400px;
    background: #ccc;
    overflow: hidden
}
#left, #right {
    float: left;
    width: 75px;
}
#mid {
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
}
#mid .box {
    margin: 0 10px;
    border-color: red
}
#left .box {
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    border-color: blue
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">
        <div class="box">left 1</div>
        <div class="box">left 2</div>
    </div>
    <div id="mid"><div class="box">mid</div></div>
    <div id="right"><div class="box">right</div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Definitely the best way to implement this. Couldn't agree more that having a `box` class makes this so much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Also take a look at this one: [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/cAwWE/1/) which has a fluid layout.

And [another one](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/cAwWE/2/) without the fixed div in the bottomleft corner.

Comment: @Wex: That was my first interpretation of OP's question. Later in his comment he explained his wish in more detail, but I found it not necessary to change my fiddle, for there are enough samples already now. Besides, this might provide some additional inspiration for Sebastian.